# How to display media title in AVPlayerController only when playerControls are visibile

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

1. I need to display the media title only when the playerControls are
   visible.
2. Don't need to customize the complete playerControls.
3. Already tried with ContentOverlayView of AVPlayerViewController. Title is visible but I need the title only when the playerControls are visible.

Answer (score 0):

As you can notice the player controller hides the controls and the status bar simultaneously so one of possible solution to observe visibility of the status bar since there is no API to observe the controls appearance. You can check `prefersStatusBarHidden` variable with `Timer` because it is not supported by KVO but don't forget to invalidate the timer after closing the player controller.

```swift
var titleLabel: UILabel?
var playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController?
var timer: Timer?

@IBAction func showPlayer() {
        
    titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 50));
    titleLabel?.text = "My Title"
    titleLabel?.textColor = .red
    
    playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController?.player = AVPlayer(url: url)
    playerViewController?.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(titleLabel!)
    playerViewController?.player?.play()
    present(playerViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.3, repeats: true) { timer in
        if let hidden = self.playerViewController?.prefersStatusBarHidden {
            self.titleLabel?.isHidden = hidden
        }
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil
}
```

Or you can check visibility globally by checking `UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.isStatusBarHidden`.